# MATLAB to Python conversion of Union

Tags: python, matlab, union

I have a 2D matrix `C` in Python and I am trying to do what is done in MATLAB.

MATLAB code:

```matlab
Tr = 5;
Td = 4;
Gr = 4;
Gd = 1;
C(union(1:(Tr+Gr),end-(Tr+Gr-1):end), :) = 0;
C(:, union(1:(Td+Gd),end-(Td+Gd-1):end)) = 0;
```

Python code:

```py
ru1 = C[:Tr+Gr]
a = np.shape(C)
ru2 = C[a[0] - (Tr + Gr -1):]
C[ru1.union(ru2),:]= 0
```

However, I am getting an error on `union`. How can I take the union of these arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `numpy.union1d`. `union()` only works on sets ( defined with `{}` )